# I am trying to authenticate with OAuth 2.0 in exchange online for IMAP using client credential flow

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, exchange-server, imap

I have successfully got the access token.
But While authenticating the error says authentication failed. I have checked all the settings and scope that should be configured in exchange online app registration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlR2r.png)
my code is like this and the scope i have used for it is:
string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

I also tried changing the scope
like:
https://outlook.office365.com/.default

Ps. Made the necessary changes in api permission after changing the scope

```
  var options = new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                TenantId = tenantId
              
            };

            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
                .Build();


            var authenticationResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("email", authenticationResult.AccessToken);

            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also couple of steps to make sure IMAP is turn on for your organization:

1. In Microsoft 365 admin portal on 'Org settings' screen turn on
   'Modern authentication' and check IMAP protocol
2. Make sure that for a specific account (on the 'Users' tab) IMAP is turned on 'Mail'/'Manage
   email apps' screen
3. In MS AD/Entra ID disable Security defaults (make also sure no 'Conditional Access' policies block IMAP)

You can find more details here:
https://www.limilabs.com/blog/office365-enable-imap-pop3-smtp

Client credential flow is tricky. You need to create a service principal using PS command:

```
New-ServicePrincipal
 -AppId <APPLICATION_ID>
 -ServiceId <OBJECT_ID> 
 [-Organization <ORGANIZATION_ID>]
```

and add permissions to a specific mailbox:

```
Add-MailboxPermission
 -Identity "<USER@your-domain.onmicrosoft.com>"
 -User <OBJECT_ID>
 -AccessRights FullAccess
```

Here's a detailed description:
https://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-client-credential-flow-office365-exchange-imap-pop3-smtp